# Is this an acceptable way to do a proof?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm going through the introduction to Apostol's Calculus and am trying to prove the theorems that he gives.

Would this be an example of an acceptable proof?

> THM 1.9 If $a\neq (0)$ then $b/a = b \cdot a^{-1}$

Proof:

> =$\frac ba = b\cdot a^{-1}$
>
> > Multiplying each side by a we get:
> >
> > > $a(\frac ba)=(b \cdot a^{-1}) \cdot a $
> > >
> > > > For the left side we use Thm1.8 and obtain b.
> > > >
> > > > > For the right side we use the associative, reciprocal, and identity axioms to obtain:
> > > > >
> > > > > > $=^{1.8} b =(b \cdot a^{-1}) \cdot a =b \dot (a \cdot a^{-1})= b \cdot 1 = b$
>
> 1.8 Given a and b with a $\neq 0$, there is exactly one x such taht ax=b. This x is denoted by b/a and is called the quoteient of b and a. In particular, 1/a is also written $a^{-1}$ and is called the reciprocal of a.

Comment: Proofs are generally intended to be read by people, and when you communicate with people you use words, sentences, paragraphs. A proof should be an *explanation*.

Comment: The book by Apostol you are reading contains lots of proofs. You should strive for yours to look like his.

Comment: Thanks Mariano, I appreciate your advice, but I have seen several different proofs of certain concepts that Apostol also does, and I often like the method of proving of others to his. For brevity here, I did not list the axioms that I used. But is the method that I used here an acceptable way of a proof?

Comment: If you handed me such a proof in an exam, I would give it back to you and tell you to explain in writing what you are doing. Again, a sequence of equalities with footnotes is *not* an explanation.

Comment: What I meant was: notice that when he writes a proof, he write sentences, logically connected to explain the line of his reasoning. A proof is  *text*.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I am used to doing it this way because in Spivak's book he often just manipulates equations. Is the way that I changed it better or still not enough explanation?

Comment: I don; t know what book of Spivak you have in mind, but I surely doubt he has published a proof resssembling what you have written in the question even from afar. Spivak, as Apostol, writes sentences connected in the form of paragraphs. There is no way around it, I am sorry to tell you. If you write a mathematical paper or book with proofs in the style you used in the question, it should be rejected by every sensible journal or editor —I wish every math intructor would also reject such a thing, forcing students to learn how to actually write a proof.

Comment: I don't have a teacher to accept anything. But what I mean about Spivak is that when I check my work against the solutions in the back of his book all I see is the manipulation of equations. Sure, if I was writing a mathematical paper or a book I would provide superfluous explanation, but seeing as how I am merely trying to check if my logic is correct I spare mathxchange users from having to read extraneous material.

Comment: Well, my point is that in thinking that the explanation is *superfluous* or *extraneous* you could not be further away from being right. Moreover, the idea that when you need to write a paper you will magically turn on the ability to write well-written proofs and that meanwhile you can get by by stringing equalities in a line is really counterfactual. Writing proofs correctly is an **extremely hard** thing, and pretty much everyone needs as much practice as they can get. Your most exigent teacher should be yourself, and you should be the least easy person to convince about what you write.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and I agree with you, but I'm writing this proof as if it were to appear right in the book where it was given. Previous to it were thorough explanations of the axioms given and other proofs such as 1.8 used to manipulate this proof. Here, I have listed the axioms used as well as a proof, namely 1.8, which is assumed to be previously proven. Other than the few sentences which I gave here, what would be an example of further explanation that I could give.

Comment: @AlexHeuman: Note, that unless you have specifically made it clear that the steps that you make are equivalences, then your current argumentation does not prove the claim. Why? Consider this as an example: $1=2\Rightarrow 1\cdot 0=2\cdot 0\Rightarrow 0=0$, hence $1=2$. What went wrong? By beginning with the claim and proceeding to something that is true, e.g. $0=0$ or $b=b$ in your case, does **not** prove that the claim itself is true. I think Mariano addressed this very nicely in his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three complete sentences in one paragraph.

> By definition, we have $a\cdot a^{-1}=1$. If we multiply by $b$ both sides of this equation, we see that $(a\cdot a^{-1})\cdot b=1\cdot b=b$ and then, associating differently the first member of this last equality, that  $a\cdot (a^{-1}\cdot b)=b$. It follows that $b/a=a^{-1}\cdot b$, which equals $b\cdot a^{-1}$ simply because multiplication is commutative.

The worst problem with what your wrote is that you started with what you wanted to prove and modified it until you got something you knew, while in the immense majority of cases you should start from what you know and get to what you want to know. In many cases, this is just a matter of rewriting, but writing things in your direction is generlly *harder* and takes much more work to do correctly.

A different way to phrase it is:

> As $a\cdot (b\cdot a^{-1})=a\cdot(a^{-1}\cdot b)=(a\cdot a^{-1})\cdot b=1\cdot b=b$, by definition we have $b\cdot a^{-1} = b/a$.

or, if you really must,

> > As \begin{align}a\cdot (b\cdot a^{-1})&=a\cdot(a^{-1}\cdot b) &&\text{by commutativity of $\cdot$}\\&=(a\cdot a^{-1})\cdot b &&\text{by associativity of $\cdot$}\\&=1\cdot b&&\text{by the definition of $a^{-1}$}\\&=b&&\text{because $1$ is a unit for $\cdot$,}\end{align} by definition we have $b\cdot a^{-1} = b/a$.

Comment: Extremely important point there what you made about "starting with what he wanted to prove". This way of thinking is a common mistake that especially freshmen tend to have trouble with. The fact, that the claim implies something that is true, as $b=b$ e.g., does not imply that the claim itself is true. However, while it works with equivalences, it is still very unpreferable approach in my opinion. +1 for that.

Comment: Thanks Mariano for this detailed answer and for sticking with me. I understand a lot better now.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have *proved* that $\rm\: a(ba^{-1}) = b,\:$ then you can conclude by saying: by the *uniqueness theorem 1.8,* for solutions of $\rm\:a x = b,\:$ we  deduce that $\rm\:ba^{-1}\! = b/a.\:$ The proof should *explicitly* say that it invokes a uniqueness theorem (a standard and powerful way of deducing equalities).

Thus you need only use your axioms to prove that $\rm\: a(ba^{-1}) = b,\:$ then conclude as above.

As for the attempted proof, it seems to prove that $\rm\: b/a = ba^{-1}\Rightarrow\: b = b,\:$ by multiplying both sides by $\rm\:a,\:$ then applying field axioms. I cannot judge if this is correct proof that $\rm\,b/a = ba^{-1}$ from what little is written. It could possibly denote the following correct proof. Let $\rm\:x' = b/a\:$ and $\rm\:x = ba^{-1}.\:$ Multiplying both by $\rm\ a\ $ shows that $\rm\: ax' = b = ax,\:$ so, by the uniqueness theorem, we deduce that $\rm\:x' = x.\:$  But it could also denote a possibly incorrect proof that starts by already assuming what is to be proved, then attempting to deduce a true equality (a common error).

In any case, as I said at the start, you need only prove that $\rm\:ax =b\:$ for $\rm\:x = ba^{-1}.$ There's no need to prove also that $\rm\:x' = b/a\:$ is a solution, since that is true definition, i.e. by Theorem 1.8 there *exists* a *unique* solution, denoted by $\rm\:b/a.\:$ If you've proved that $\rm\:ba^{-1}$ is a solution, then it follows immediately that $\rm\:ba^{-1}\! = b/a\:$ by the *uniqueness* half of the Theorem 1.8. The proof is done.